# Concatenate Multiple values in one cell excell vba

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I am using two workbooks to search for missing information that is in one book but not in the other.  My code works but in some instances I have multiple values being returned and only one value is entered in to the cell, I need to concatenate the other values in to the same cell with a "," in between each value

```
  Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
  Dim wbnew As Workbook
  Dim c As Range, FR As Variant
  Dim d As Range
  Dim e As Range

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False


  Set w2 = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").ActiveSheet
  Set w1 = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").ActiveSheet



For Each c In w1.Range("C2", w1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("C"), 0)
If IsNumeric(FR) Then
c.Offset(, 1).Value = w2.Range("D" & FR).Value
End If

Next c
```

Comment: If you mean that there are multiple matches, `Application.Match` only returns one match... you'll need a different approach.

Comment: Thanks BigBen, any recommendations?  I didn't realize application match gave only one match. Learning a lot from you!

Comment: If you're working with text, you may be able to use the [`Filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filter-function) function.

Comment: Unfortunately the Filter function doesn't help, I have 40 workbooks that need to be checked.  A VBA code would be faster.

Comment: `Filter` *is* VBA... you can click the link :-)

Comment: Hi BigBen, I tried using the filter function, but it won't work, I'm trying to compare two workbooks and need to match column C in each workbook.  Upon a match I need to copy the values of Workbook2's column D's corresponding cell to Workbook1.  Workbook2 has multiple instances of the same value in it's column C but the value for the coresponding column D is different for each thus I need to find all the same values in Workbook2 ColumnC and copy All the values in D that correspond with C column values and copy them all into one cell in Workbook1. Hope that made sense :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: tested this one...

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet, c As Range
    Dim arr, r As Long, result As String, sep As String

    Set w1 = Sheet1
    Set w2 = Sheet2

    arr = w2.Range("C2:C" & w2.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Resize(, 2).Value

    For Each c In w1.Range(w1.Range("C2"), w1.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        If Len(c) > 0 Then
            result = ""
            sep = ""
            For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
                If arr(r, 1) = c Then
                    result = result & sep & arr(r, 2)
                    sep = ","
                End If
            Next r
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = result
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but this made the system hang.  Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: How much data do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue with the follow code.  Thank you everyone for your help! :)

Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
   Dim Cl As Range
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set w2 = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").ActiveSheet

Set w1 = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").ActiveSheet

With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

```
  For Each Cl In w2.Range("C2", w2.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
     If Not .Exists(Cl.Value) Then
        .Add Cl.Value, Cl.Offset(, 1).Value
     Else
        .Item(Cl.Value) = .Item(Cl.Value) & "," & Cl.Offset(, 1).Value
     End If
  Next Cl
  For Each Cl In w1.Range("C2", w1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
     If .Exists(Cl.Value) Then Cl.Offset(, 1).Value = .Item(Cl.Value)
  Next Cl
 End With`
```